# ec2 instance is hanging when we move the larges files to tmp directory

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-ec2, ansible

When I move around 100gb files to `/tmp` directory with allocating 300gb,
When I tried using ansible for move file to tmp directory then I am getting below error

```json
{"changed": false, 
 "failed": true,
 "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 172.31.49.31 closed.\r\n",
 "module_stdout": "",
 "msg": "MODULE FAILURE",
 "rc": 0}
```

I have used ansible code as like below

```
- name: Move solr_product folder to /tmp        
  command: mv /opt/tmp/solr_product /tmp/
```

when I am trying to move files using linux command
inside of ec2 instance then getting below error

`remote side unexpectedly closed network connection`

I have used linux commands like below

```bash
$ rsync -av /opt/tmp/solr_product /tmp/  
$ mv /opt/tmp/solr_product /tmp/
```

available storage like below

```
[ubuntu@ip-xx-xx-xx-xxx /]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs         16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            16G  612K   16G   1% /run
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1  350G  5.3G  345G   2% /
tmpfs           300G   20G  281G   7% /tmp
tmpfs           3.1G     0  3.1G   0% /run/user/820
tmpfs           3.1G     0  3.1G   0% /run/user/1002
tmpfs           3.1G     0  3.1G   0% /run/user/0
tmpfs           3.1G     0  3.1G   0% /run/user/1000/
```

Comment: What did you try to fix these problems?

Comment: We tried all the ways as mentioned in the post above @rkochar

Comment: Is `/opt/tmp/solr_product` directory present on the same ec2 instance? I don't find it in `df -h` output. Or is it mounted on `/`? Also let me know where `home` is mounted? And the output of `$HOME` env var..

Comment: Yes /opt/tmp/solr_product is present in same ec2 instance! /tmp/solr_product is present under /opt directory so it is not visible in df -h output! The home directory is mounted on / (you can see that above output) @harshavmb

Comment: /opt/tmp/solr_product and /tmp/solr_product both directory are different, opt is mounted on / and tmp directory is mounted on /tmp. With opt we are able to work properly and facing issues with /tmp directory.@harshavmb